# How can I fix pagination? I want to put pagination in lower left but If I put 3 items my pagination buttons it became vertical instead of horizontal

Tags: php, html, css

[image: here is the image if pagination that display vertically instead of horizontal]

Here is my code and image of pagination displaying vertical instead of horizontal, Can someone help me fix this pagination, Thanks and sorry in advance if my code is messed up and I don't know how to fix pagination displaying in vertical.

```
public function showProducts(){
        $results_per_page = 8;  

        //find the total number of results stored in the database  
        $query = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id ASC";  
        $result = $this->db->query($query);  
        $number_of_result = mysqli_num_rows($result);  
        // $total_result = $this->shopMdl->getProducts();

        //determine the total number of pages available  
        $number_of_page = ceil ($number_of_result / $results_per_page);  
        //echo $number_of_page;

        //determine which page number visitor is currently on  
        if (isset ($_GET['page']) ) {  
            $page = $_GET['page']; 
            // echo $page;
        } else {  
            $page = 1;   
        }  

        //determine the sql LIMIT starting number for the results on the displaying page  
        $page_first_result = ($page-1) * $results_per_page;  

        //retrieve the selected results from database   
        $query = "SELECT * FROM products LIMIT " . $page_first_result . ',' . $results_per_page;  
        $result = $this->db->query($query); 
        // // $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
        // echo var_dump($result);
                    
        //display the retrieved result on the webpage  
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {  
            ?>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <div class="card mx-auto mb-5">
                        <?php echo "<img src='./productImages/".$row['product_img']."'>";?>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title text-center font-weight-bold">Cozumei</h5>
                            <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1" /> 
                            <h5 class="card-text text-center"><?php echo $row['description']; ?></h5>
                            <p class="card-text text-center"><?php echo $row['price']; ?></p>

                            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row["item_name"]; ?>" />  
                        <input type="hidden" name="hidden_description" value="<?php echo $row["description"]; ?>" /> 
                        <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $row["price"]; ?>"  />
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Add to Cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php }

            for ($btn=1; $btn <=$number_of_page; $btn++) { 
                echo '<button class="btn btn-dark mx-1"><a href="shop?page='.$btn.'"
                class="text-light">'.$btn.'</a></button>';
            } 
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I see your pagination is wrapped in a grid or flex element, what is the wrapped of your products ?

If that's the case, try putting your pagination outside of this element and it should work correctly.

Comment: <!--Product Lists-->
<div class="container pt-5">
    <h2 class="">All Products</h2>
    <div class="row mx-auto pt-4">
        <?php $shopCntrl->showProducts(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Product Lists-->

Comment: thats the code, sorry if its messed up.

Comment: Try inspecting your "row mx-auto pt-4" div, does it have a display grid or flex rule ? If that's the case, try putting this div inside the showProducts method and wrap it around the col-sm-6 div so the pagination is outside

Comment: how can I put the div "row mx-auto pt-4" inside the showProducts method? or I'll just wrap it around the by putting col-sm-6?